# Debouncing ng-keypress

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, keypress, debouncing

Does anyone have any pointers for me to debounce the keypress event in angular? I can't get it to debounce. And I know for sure because I'm using $log.debug to print out the keys pressed, and the amount of times it fires off is not at the debounce rate.

I have set it up like this:

```
<div ng-keypress="doSomething"></div>
```

and in my controller (not that I have included underscore.js to utilize its debounce method in this instance):

```
...
$scope.doSomething = function(event, keyEvent) {
    var keypressed = String.fromCharCode(keyEvent.which).toUpperCase();
    _.debounce(handleKeyPress(keypressed), 500);
}

function handleKeyPress(keypressed) {
    //do something with the keypress
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by the amount of times it fires off is not at the debounce rate?

Comment: When calling `_.debounce(handleKeyPress(keypressed), 500);` you are resolving `handleKeyPress(keypressed)` and passing the result to be debounced. You should be passing a function that can be called. Something like:

`var bounceable = function() {handleKeyPress(keypressed)}`
`_.debounce(bounceable, 500);`

Comment: Hi Enzey, 
That made perfect sense.  I've applied it, but it doesn't run.  I don't get any errors either.  I tried putting just a console.log statement inside the debounce function and it doesn't even call that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
$scope.doSomething = _.debounce(function(event, keyEvent) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
    // Do something here
    });
}, 500);
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QsXoYOUhAiQulfB6ZJZG?p=preview)

As @Enzey said, `_.debounce()` returns a "debounced" function that needs to be called somewhere to have any effect. And you need to call `$apply()` in order to trigger a digest cycle. Otherwise any changes on the model made within the debounced function won't update the view.

**Update**

It turned out that what the OP really wanted was a throttled function. Below is another code snippet using `_.throttle()`:

```
$scope.doSomething = _.throttle(function($event) {
    if ($scope.$$phase) return; // Prevents 'digest already in progress' errors

    $scope.$apply(function() {
        // Do something here
    });
}, 100);
```

Comment: This is very close.  I have played with your plunkr code, and have set the delay to 100ms.  If you kept your keypress on a letter for a second, you should get around 10 prints of the same letter.  But you don't.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JohnFu You seem to be confusing `debounce` with `throttle`. A *debounced* function will only be executed if it's not called again within the specified delay. On the other hand, a *throttled* function will be executed at most once per every X milliseconds. I'll update the plunker to show both. Let me know if that's what you want and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Many thanks for that.  I had no idea and that makes sense.  You learn something new everyday.